# In which case it is not safe to cast an object of base class to EMPTY derived class

Tags: c++

I use the following code to access a protected member of an object.

```
class Base {
protected:
    void foo();
};

class PublicBase : public Base {
public:
    static void bar(Base *obj) {
        static_assert(sizeof(PublicBase) == sizeof(Base), "Not today");
        static_cast<PublicBase *>(obj)->foo();
    }
};
```

Can I assume that provided code is safe to use (in theory and in practice)?

Comment: Why do you need to cast in order to do this?

Comment: Does the word "safe" mean anything? Depending on the value of the function argument, your program either has undefined behaviour or it doesn't. Just like `printf`.

Comment: It's safe when the object really is of that type, and at no other time. If you think you need do this, you're already making a mistake of some kind.

Comment: Probably in no case this is safe. I can't quite find the "if you do this, it's UB" statement on the standard, but I'm fairly sure it's either unspecified or undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, no. In practice, maybe, as long as there are no virtual functions involved. The relevant passage in the standard is 5.2.9 (2):

> An lvalue of type "*cv1* B", where B is a class type, can be cast to type "reference to *cv2* D," where D is a class derived from B, if a valid standard conversion from "pointer to D" to "pointer to B" exists, *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*, and B is neither a virtual base class of D nor a base class of a virtual base class of D. The result has type "*cv2* D." (...) If the object of type "*cv1* B" is actually a subobject of an object of type D, the result refers to the enclosing object of type D. **Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined.**

Emphasis mine.

EDIT: Well, my first approach at a dirty-but-legal hack didn't work, which is nice because the loophole I thought existed was one that shouldn't. There's no way to legally call `foo` on `*obj` that I can find -- as well there shouldn't be, if `protected` is to have any meaning at all -- so the best I can offer are two ideas for workarounds:

Firstly, if copying (or moving) back and forth is okay

```
class PublicBase : public Base {
public:
  void bar(Base *obj) {
    // upcast, perfectly legal. make a working copy into self
    *static_cast<Base*>(this) = *obj;
    // work
    foo();
    // copy back
    *obj = *this;
  }
};
```

Secondly, if you can derive from `Base` and use the new class whereever you would have used `Base` before:

```
// use this instead of Base everywhere.
class BaseWithAccess {
public:
  void publicfoo() { foo(); }
};
```

Other than that, I have nothing. Unless you can change `Base`, in which case you could just make `foo` public.

Comment: Oh. Hm, I thought it should. Give me a minute.

Comment: Yes, on second thought it makes sense that it would not. I'm afraid I can only offer paltry workarounds with limitations, then. What you're trying to do is exactly the sort of thing access specifiers are supposed to prevent.

Comment: In the first code snippet the copy constructor of the `Base` class will be called twice. It may have side effects. Thank you for a good answer anyway.